# Coderbyte Letter Changing challenge - else statement error

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, for-loop

Im doing the Letter Changes challenge in coderbyte but I'm confused as to why my code isnt working.

> Have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being
>   passed and modify it using the following algorithm.
>
> Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the
>   alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a).
>
> Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and
>   finally return this modified string.

In the last else statement, i want to add any character that isnt a letter to the "newWord". When i pass the word "hello 3" I should be getting "ifmmp 3" instead I get "hhhhhhhihhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeefeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelllllllllllmllllllllllllllllllllllllllmllllllllllllllloooooooooooooopoooooooooooo                            333333333333333333333333333undefined....." If i take that else statement out, I just get "ifmmp" without the 3. Im having trouble understanding why/how the else statement is messing it up and how could i fix this? 
Im new to coding so any help would be great.

```
    function LetterChanges(str) { 
var newWord = "";
 var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
            if( str[i] === "z"){
        newWord += alphabet.charAt(0);
      } else if(str[i] === " "){
        newWord +=" ";
      } 

    for (var j = 0; j <= alphabet.length; j++){
        if(str[i] == alphabet.charAt(j)){
                newWord += alphabet.charAt(j+1);
            }
   // this one -------------------> else {
                                    newWord = newWord + str[i]; 
                                   } 
        }

      }
      return newWord;       
    }
```

Comment: Ive checked them but im not able to pinpoint the issue. Which braces should i check?

Comment: Please debug your program by walking through it step by step in devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
    var newWord = "";
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){

        for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++){

            if(str[i] === alphabet.charAt(j)){
                if( str[i] === "z"){
                    newWord += alphabet.charAt(0);
                } 
                else {
                    newWord += alphabet.charAt(j+1);
                }
            }
            else if (alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) === -1){
               newWord += str[i];
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newWord;       
}
```

The following would be a more efficient solution

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
    var newWord = "";
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        // if it's a 'z' do not loop through alphabet string and jump straight to the next character.
        if( str[i] === "z"){
            newWord += alphabet.charAt(0);
            continue;
        } 
        for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++){
            // if they match perform replacement 
            if(str[i] === alphabet.charAt(j)){
                newWord += alphabet.charAt(j+1);
                break;
            }
            // if the current char is not contained on the alphabet string (spaces, numbers and so on...) ---> copy it as it is
            else if (alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) === -1){
               newWord += str[i];
               break;
            }
            // if the current char is contained in the alphabet string but does not match ---> do nothing
        }
    }
    return newWord;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Angelo but it didnt work. If i pass "hello" i get "hello" back.

Comment: @mgee I "translated" from Java and it was working fine for me. I'll try and see what I went wrong in the translation and post back the result

Comment: @mgee I guess I spotted the mistake in the elseif condition I used !== instead of ===. I corrected it now. Let me know how it goes. Anyway my solution could be improved in terms of efficiency. For instance Your approach of replacing "z" outside the inner for loop it's better in that sense

Comment: @mgee feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if that solved your problem